# Having null when trying to display single object using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to output a single value of an object but am getting null. Don't know where I got it wrong. Below is the JSON response I got but when I tried to display it, am geting null ;

```
{
      "success": true,
      "message": "Course Retrieved Successfully.",
      "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "course_code": "null",
        "course_name": "Greatness",
        "slug": "greatness",
        "course_fee": 10,
        "duration": "10hours",
        "start_date": "2000-09-08",
        "end_date": "2000-09-08",
       
    
        }
    
    }
```

My code below

```
const [coursedetails, setCourseDetails] = useState([])
     

    const init =()=>{
       axios.get('http://example.com/api/courses').then(response => {
           setCourseDetails(response);
            }).catch(error =>{
                console.log('error',error)
            })
    }
     

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
        
    }, []);




  return (
    <div>
      {coursedetails.data.course_name}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: What is your `response` variable value?

Comment: The first block of code is the response

Comment: just use a regular `fetch` instead of axios. unless you're intercepting any requests or making pre and post flight confligs then you really dont need axios. 

`fetch('http://example.com/api/courses').then(r => r.json()).then((response) => { setCourseDetails(response); } )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When axios gives you a response to a GET request, the data returned from the server is in a `data` property. This is a bit confusing in your example, because the data returned from the server also has a `data` property. So, in effect, you need to access `response.data.data`. You might adjust when you set the course details to instead have `setCourseDetails(response.data);`

However, you also have some mismatched types. Your `coursedetails` starts as an array, but you then set it to an axios response, which is an object. So you'll want to change that to `useState({})` or something similar.

Your JSX return value (at least, I presume it is. It's not wrapped in a return statement, but perhaps you deleted some for consciseness.) also presumes that there is always a `data` property on `coursedetails`, and a `course_name` property on that `data` property. This isn't true, for instance, at the beginning. You will want to adjust this to check for its presence, i.e. `{coursedata.data && coursedata.data.course_name ? coursedata.data : ''}`

Finally, it is helpful to track the status of async requests like this. I often use a separate state for the status, i.e. `const [status,setStatus] = useState('init');` Then right before the axios request is fired, `setStatus('loading')` and then right after it is successful, `setStatus('success')`. (And, if there's an error, `setStatus('error')`. This makes it easier to show different loading states to the user.

Comment: He could also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with the  [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) for when the properties of his object do not exist yet.

Comment: Does the current configuration of CRA compile that down to es5 yet?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to output the message, but when I tried to output value in data object I got this error response  "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, course_code, course_name, slug, course_fee, duration, start_date, end_date,}"

Comment: @GabrielGeelario you may want to ask a separate question about this if you continue to struggle with it as it's a different issue, but that error indicates you are trying to render an object directly. From your error it appears you are now directly rendering your `data` object.

Comment: @tmdesigned honestly I don't know and wouldn't want to give a (guess) of an answer.

Comment: @tmdesigned, thanks for the solution, it really helped. But I modified your code {coursedata.data && coursedata.data.course_name ? coursedata.data : ''} to {coursedata && coursedata.data ? coursedata.data.course_name : '' "} and I got the issue fixed.